# How to append TEXT inside a text file to the END of the file name of a different file?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

I have figured out how to download multiple images from flickr.com and save the tag info to a separate text file alongside the image file.

For example:

```
$ ls
2675.jpg
2675.txt

$ cat 2675.txt
_tags_mountains_daylight_oregon
```

I want to copy the tag information to the end of the file names.

Before:

```
2675.jpg
```

After:

```
2675_tags_mountains_daylight_oregon.jpg
```

Is there way to do this? Something that I can put into a bash script?

Comment: Have either of the answers below solved your problem? If so, please click the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Using a few shell-native tools:

```
for f in *.jpg
do
  mv -- "$f" "${f%.jpg}$(< ${f%.jpg}.txt ).jpg"
done
```

The `$(< ...)` syntax asks bash to read the contents of the given file. The given file is generated by stripping off the trailing `.jpg` and appending `.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

files='/path/to/files'

for file in "$files/"*.jpg; do
    tag=$(grep '_tags_' "${file/.jpg/.txt}")
    bname=${file%.jpg}
    mv "$file" "${bname}${tag}.jpg"
done
```

This will loop through all the `.jpg` files in the path you specify.

`tag` will grep for the string `_tags_` in the `.txt` file with the same name as the current `.jpg` file it's working on and be set to that whole line.

`bname` will be set to the basename of the current file it's working on (no extension)

It will then rename the file to name/tag.jpg (So in the case of the example `2675_tags_mountains_daylight_oregon.jpg`)